# Entity Framework 5 + MySQL.Data 6.6.4.0 causes NullReferenceException on data insert

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework with MySQL and it's giving me a NullReferenceException every time I try to insert data.

- I can insert data directly by creating a command but when I use Entity Framework it bombs out.
- Entity Framework will select from tables or update tables so perhaps this is something to do with the primary key

The following exception is thrown from the SaveChanges() method.

```
failed: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at MySql.Data.Entity.ListFragment.WriteSql(StringBuilder sql)
    at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.WriteSql(StringBuilder sql)
    at MySql.Data.Entity.InsertStatement.WriteSql(StringBuilder sql)
    at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlFragment.ToString()
    at MySql.Data.Entity.InsertGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree)
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
    at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree)
    at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbCommandTree commandTree)
    at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree)
    at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.CreateCommand(UpdateTranslator translator, Dictionary`2 identifierValues)
    at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
    at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
    at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
    at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
    at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
```

EF 5

```
public decimal CreateAlertNotification2(ulong alertServiceId, Alerting.alert_service_notification_type notificationType, string recipientName, string recipientEndpoint)
        {
            using (risk_fleetEntities dbContext = new risk_fleetEntities())
            {
                var newNotification = new alert_service_notification();
                newNotification.sys_alert_service_id = alertServiceId;
                newNotification.name = recipientName;
                newNotification.notification_type = Enum.GetName(typeof(Alerting.alert_service_notification_type), notificationType);
                newNotification.recipient = recipientEndpoint;
                dbContext.alert_service_notification.AddObject(newNotification);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();

                return newNotification.id;
            }
        }
```

MySQL 5

```
CREATE TABLE `alert_service_notification` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  `sys_alert_service_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `notification_type` ENUM("SMS", "Email"),
  `name` CHAR(50),
  `recipient` CHAR(50),
  FOREIGN KEY (`sys_alert_service_id`) REFERENCES `alert_service`(`id`) 
);
```

Comment: Please , show your data storing code...

Comment: Also, entity framework seems to convert MySQL bigint(20) unsigned into a C# decimal. Why?

Comment: @fireydude avoid unsigned like the plague if you're using the entity framework, it causes nothing but constant pain. The EF doesn't support unsigned ints, so it has to store them in decimal as Int64's not big enough

Comment: You have answered my question @mattmanser. I just needed to get rid of the unsigned variables in the primary key and that fixed it.

Comment: Cool, I just remembered what's probably causing the actual error, so I've added as an answer just in case people stumble over it when googling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EF doesn't support unsigned ints, so in this case it has to store the bigint as decimal as Int64's not big enough (9,223,372,036,854,775,807 max value vs unsigned bigint's 18,446,744,073,709,551,615). It will also store an unsigned int as `Int64` instead of `Int32` for the same reason.

If you try and change the type in the EF designer it doesn't quite do everything correctly and throws errors like this at runtime. You can actually open the edmx and edit it to fix this, you trick the EF into assuming the column isn't really unsigned. Simply find all references of your column and make sure none of them mention `Int64`/`decimal` (depending if you want an `Int32`/`Int64`). However if you are doing this, your database could possibly return invalid values if you ever went over the max value.

So the easier and correct fix is not to use unsigned or change the existing columns from unsigned. Certain MySQL designer tools default to unsigned id columns, so watch out for that!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was very simple. Just edited the database to have no "unsigned" variables, and built the model from that. Works like a charm, and no manual editing needed. Also, changing them back to unsigned after generating the model seems to have no issues. :)